# .parents().eq(2) seems to be skipping element

Tags: jquery, html

As part of a Chrome extension I have a line of code that looks for elements on a page that's part of a game and adds some html. The page I'm on has a couple divs in a row without a class or ID and I'm trying to target the first one to add my html. There is an h2 element that contains unique text so I'm targeting that and then trying to use parents().eq(x) to get to the div I want. If I use eq(1) it gets the parent of the h2 but, if I use eq(2) it skips the second div moving up the tree and instead targets the element above it.

This is my line of code:

```js
$("h2:contains(New Amsterdam)").parents().eq(1).prepend("<span class=\"HideFJcontainer\" style=\"font-size:18px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=\"checkbox\" Id=\"HideFJtrophy\" title=\"When checked your trophies will be hidden\">&nbsp;&nbsp;Hide/Show</span>");
```

The HTML of the section page I'm working with is:

```html
<div class="container extraBottom">
  <div id="snackbar"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
    <h1>Rogues Gallery</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>New Amsterdam
```

When I use eq(1) it adds my span before the first div above the h2 but, if I use eq(2) it puts it before the div with an ID of snackbar.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

*****Example 1 using eq(1)*****

```
<div class="container extraBottom">
        <div id="snackbar"></div>
        <div id="FJholder"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h1>Rogues Gallery</h1>
        </div>
            <div><span class="HideFJcontainer" style="font-size:18px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="HideFJtrophy" title="When checked your trophies will be hidden" checked="checked">&nbsp;&nbsp;Hide/Show</span>
                <div>
                    <h2>New Amsterdam</span>
                        </h2>
```

*****Example 2 using eq(2)*****

```
<div class="container extraBottom">
        <span class="HideFJcontainer" style="font-size:18px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="HideFJtrophy" title="When checked your trophies will be hidden" checked="checked">&nbsp;&nbsp;Hide/Show</span>
        <div id="snackbar"></div>
        <div id="FJholder"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h1>Rogues Gallery</h1>
        </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h2>New Amsterdam</span>
                        </h2>
```

Comment: `eq()` is zero-based, so `eq(1)` is the gandparent, and `eq(2)` is the great-grandparent. I think you need `parents().eq(0)` or just `closest('div')` instead, but I'm not 100% certain where you're trying to inject the `span`

Answer (score 0):

> If I use eq(1) it gets the parent of the h2...

No, it gets the *parent* of the parent of the `h2`, because [`eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) starts with `0`. `parents` returns a jQuery set where the first entry (`.eq(0)`) is the parent, the next is the grandparent (`.eq(1)`), and so on.

If you want the span inserted in the parent of the parent of the `h2`, `eq(1)` is the correct one to use. I've added borders to make clearer what's going on:

```js
$("h2:contains(New Amsterdam)").parents().eq(1).prepend("<span class=\"HideFJcontainer\" style=\"font-size:18px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=\"checkbox\" Id=\"HideFJtrophy\" title=\"When checked your trophies will be hidden\">&nbsp;&nbsp;Hide/Show</span>");
```

```css
.parent {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.grandparent {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container extraBottom">
    <div id="snackbar"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h1>Rogues Gallery</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="grandparent">
        <div class="parent">
            <h2>New Amsterdam</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For some strange reason when I use eq(1) it's inserting my span between the parent div and the grandparent div.  :-(

Comment: @ShcFinalJudgement - Define "between." :-) It's certainly not wrapping your parent div with the span. In the above you can see that the span ends up being a sibling element to the parent div, just previous to it. Where do you want it to be instead?

Comment: @ShcFinalJudgement - Not with the code and markup in the question; see the answer above.

Comment: So something else must be going on because it's not working the way you've explained it. It seems like it should so there must be something else effecting it.

Comment: @ShcFinalJudgement - It sounds as though the DOM structure quoted in the question is incorrect.

Comment: Does eq(x) need to be used with parents() or can it be used on it's own to move up the tree? Would `$("h2:contains(New Amsterdam)").eq(2)` select the div with a class of grandparent in your example html?

Comment: @ShcFinalJudgement - See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq). `eq` just isolates one entry from the jQuery set you call it on. So yes, in this case, the fact we're calling it on the set from `parents()` is important (I call this out in the first paragraph of the answer).

Comment: I added some html blocks to my original post copied from the page using both eq(1) and eq(2) so you can see the strange behavior. This all part of a Chrome extension so I'm able to make changes to the code and reload the unpacked extension to see the differences. Changing from 1 to 2 seems to be moving farther up the tree than it should unless I'm misunderstanding the way eq() works.

Comment: @ShcFinalJudgement - Your example of `eq(1)` is exactly what the answer above does. Again: *"...the span ends up being a sibling element to the parent div, just previous to it. Where do you want it to be instead?"*

Comment: I'm trying to end up with 
<span class="HideFJcontainer" style="font-size:18px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="HideFJtrophy" title="When checked your trophies will be hidden" checked="checked">&nbsp;&nbsp;Hide/Show</span>
<div>
        <div>
            <h2>New Amsterdam</h2>

Answer (score 0):

It gets the parent of the parent of the `h2`, because `eq`starts with 0.

parents returns a jQuery, set with the first entry (.eq(0). next to the grandparent ('eq(1).